# GORM: Reference to same table

Tags: sqlite, go, go-gorm

I'm trying to create a model that has a reference to the same table.

Like this:

```golang
import "gorm.io/gorm"

type Model struct {
    gorm.Model
    Code   string `bson:"code" json:"code" gorm:"uniqueIndex"`
    Name   string `bson:"name" json:"name"`
    Parent *Model `bson:"parent" json:"parent" gorm:"foreignKey:Parent"`
}
```

But when I try to create a new model, I'm getting this error: `failed to set value 0 to field Parent`.

How do I reference a field to an item in the same table?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer, you need to set the `Parent` as an uint and then set the ID when creating/updating.

Like this:

```golang
type Model struct {
    gorm.Model
    Code   string `bson:"code" json:"code" gorm:"uniqueIndex,primaryKey"`
    Name   string `bson:"name" json:"name"`
    Parent *uint  `bson:"parent" json:"parent" gorm:"foreignKey:Parent"`
}
```